# Java command line opens a useless gui on osx

Tags: java, macos, scala, maven

I created a Scala app and package it as a jar file with [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), the package uses the Weka library from the maven repo (I added it as a dependency in the build.sbt file).

The thing is, in osx, when I use the command line version of a weka classifier (e.g. `java -cp myapp.jar weka.classifier.foo -t input.arff`) using my app as the classpath, although the classifier executes just right, it opens an "empty" gui (actually it doesn't open anything but it shows in the osx task bar like a new application). It's kind of annoying since I have to execute many classifications via the command line and osx keeps creating a new focus on the open gui). However, if I use weka.jar as the classpath (e.g. `java -cp weka.jar weka.classifier.foo -t input.arff`), this doesn't happen.

Now, the problem is I have some functions from my app and when I execute them it opens also an "empty" gui (again, it doesn't actually open any visible gui, but it shows in the taskbar an application). I'm far from being a java expert, maybe it has something to do with the manifest, but I don't know.

I thank you very much for your time and help!